# See Hibernate’s query parameters when using Logback

Tags: hibernate, logback

I want to see the actual parameters of my SQL queries when I use Hibernate. I add this to my `logback.xml` to see the queries (with question marks):

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
```

I have read about setting `org.hibernate.type` to `TRACE` in order to see the parameters. I tried it, but to no effect. Note that I use Logback as my logging framework, not Log4j. I suspect that this is responsible.

Is there any special configuration necessary or possible, or do I have to resort to [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/)?

Comment: Did you set `hibernate.format_sql` property to `true` in your JPA or hibernate configuration file?

Comment: No, I haven’t, but that is only a question of formatting.